# How i get social media icons to header?

Tags: html, css, header

I am a beginner and how i get those icons to blue color header? I dont know so much about attributes and properties so well for now. I need your help to get those icons to header . I hope i  look like
{  WELCOME                (icons inline)  }

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SAMPLE 1</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: rgb(240, 233, 233);
      }
      .header h1 {
        color:rgb(255, 51, 0);
        font-family:"Pacifico", cursive ;
        padding-left: 30px;
      }
      .header {
      background-color: #09e0f8;
      padding:20px;
      border-radius: 70px;
    }
    .social {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
      padding:0;
      margin-right: 10px;
      float:right;
    }



      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header"><h1>WELCOME</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="social"><img class="insta" src="instagram.png" width="30px"></li>
        <li class="social"><img class="face" src="facebook.png" width="30px"></li>
        <li class="social"><img class="twi" src="twitter.png" width="30px"> </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
   
 
      
      
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you intending to do with the icons, is it the positioning on the header?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use `display:flex` on the container of the items.
That way you don't need to deal with padding + margins weird combinations (you will absolutely need to use margins and padding in the future but there is no need for your case)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SAMPLE 1</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: rgb(240, 233, 233);
      }
      .header h1 {
        color:rgb(255, 51, 0);
        font-family:"Pacifico", cursive ;
        padding-left: 30px;
      }
      .header {
      background-color: #09e0f8;
      padding:20px;
      display:flex;
      border-radius: 70px;
      align-items: center;

    }
    .social {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
      padding:0;
    }



      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header"><h1>WELCOME</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="social"><img class="insta" src=https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdx-QjbrMwdgCSQMk4x2sP-iFXr0poxubFKg&usqp=CAU" width="30px"></li>
        <li class="social"><img class="face" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdx-QjbrMwdgCSQMk4x2sP-iFXr0poxubFKg&usqp=CAU" width="30px"></li>
        <li class="social"><img class="twi" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdx-QjbrMwdgCSQMk4x2sP-iFXr0poxubFKg&usqp=CAU" width="30px"> </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
   
 
      
      
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Just make sure to adjust your image to fit.

Please note that I also added `align-items: center;` to adjust the icons but you change this ass need